# Split Flash AS2 array into individual variables

Tags: flash, variables, split, actionscript-2

My string: s5_1

Basically, I want to split the string so that it results two variables, one as "s5" and the other "1".

For example

```
variable1 = "0";
variable2 = "0";
var mystring:String = "s5_1";
//SPLIT CODE HERE
trace(variable1); //this will trace "s5"
trace(variable2); //this will trace "1"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which programming language/environment is this?

Comment: Flash Action Script 2, sorry I should've wrote that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split` method of `String` will split a string into an array of strings based on a delimiter:

```
variable1 = "0";
variable2 = "0";
var mystring:String = "s5_1";
var parts = mystring.split("_");
variable1 = parts[0];
variable2 = parts[1];
trace(variable1); //this will trace "s5"
trace(variable2); //this will trace "1"
```